# Spring MVC - JSON Response from the JDBC - not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers

Tags: json, spring, jsp

I am getting the following error and wondering to know how to resolve this:

```
 The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
```

I have attached my controller code and the JSP view to render that result from the database call:

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class JsonController {

    private static final String EMPLOYEE_DROP_DOWN = "employeeRequest";
    @Autowired
    EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;
    @Autowired
    EmployeeDAOImpl employeeDAOImpl;
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext context;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/employees/json/dropdown.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/xml, application/json", produces = {
            "application/json", "application/xml" })
    public String getEmployeeDropDown(Map<String, Object> model) {
        Employee employees = new Employee();
        model.put("employees", employees);

        List<String> employeeList = new ArrayList<String>();

        List<Employee> details = employeeDAO.getEmployeeRelationshipList();
        for (Employee record : details) {
            employeeList.add(record.getLastName());
        }
        model.put("employeeList", employeeList);

        return EMPLOYEE_DROP_DOWN;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/employees/json/data.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Employee post( @ModelAttribute Employee employees) {
        System.out.println(employees.getFirstName() + " " + employees.getLastName());
        return employees;
    }

}
```

JSP View Page:

```
<%@ include file="/WEB-INF/views/includes/taglibs.jsp" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <%-- for responsive side --%>
    <script src="<c:url value="../../resources/js/bootstrap.js" />"></script>

    <title>Employee Information</title>
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <p align="center">Please choose the last name and provide the corresponding first name...</p>
    <form:form method="GET" action="/spring-jdbc/employees/json/data.htm" modelAttribute="employees">
        <table align="center" cellpadding="10">
            <tr>
                <td>Employee Last Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <form:select path="lastName">
                        <form:option value="NONE" label=" select the employee last name "/>
                        <form:options items="${employeeList}"/>
                    </form:select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Employee First Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <form:input type="text" path="firstName"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Save Changes"/>
            </td>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        sendAjax();
    });

    function sendAjax(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "/spring-jdbc/employees/json/data.htm",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: "{\"First Name\": \""+lastName+"\", \"Last Name\": \""+firstName+"\"}",
            mimeTypes: 'application/json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(data){
                alert(data.firstName + " " + data.lastName);
            },
            error:function(data, status, er){
                alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I get the result in JSON response?
I have Jackson-mapper-asl, and other required dependencies in pom.xml file.

Result I am trying to get:

```
data: {
"First Name": name,
"Last Name": name
}
```

For example: the formation I put in the form field is giving me an error.

Comment: how are you making the request? Are you specifying the accept header correctly?

Comment: You are doing a `POST`, which is correct for form submission, but the controller only responds to a `GET`. Also, your api is messed up -- the file extensions imply an html response, but you're trying to return only json or xml.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a `POST`, which is correct for form submission, but the controller only responds to a `GET`. Also, your api is messed up -- the file extensions imply an html response, but you're trying to return only json or xml. The rest of the code is really messed up too -- but you haven't asked about that.

Comment: Not sure about the code mess. But getEmployeeDropDown that methods gets the Data from the Database for the drop down. and in the form field, as you see, I have a input field where I can put the input manually while one is drop down. So my question at this point is: how can I improve this code and get the JSON response for that gets lastName from the drop down and the firstName manually entering it? Thank you for the response.